# Why GPS time is wrong and differs on a hour?

Tags: android, gps

Is GPS location time depend on something? Can't understand.

I do:

`Log.d(TAG, "gps=" + mLastLocation.getTime()+ ", onboard=" + System.currentTimeMillis());`

got in logs: gps=1460650390000, onboard=1460646790765

so, gps=UTC 16:13:10, onboard=UTC 15:13:10

same time on http://currentmillis.com -- UTC time 15:13:17

so , device time is ok, satellites time is wrong. 
**Why?** Something very weird. It is old android 2.3.

<strike>**UPDATED**  now UTC 20:29:00, GPS shows 00:29:00 (w/o timezone of course)</strike>

Comment: So I dug up this old question, but I currently have the same problem with a device. Did you come up with a solution for your problem? Which device(s) where affected in your case? My current one is a Terra 803 with Android 4.4.2, quite a cheap tablet but anyway...

Comment: I dropped any effords. But try to change timezone AND quit from your app. App doesn't see TMZ changes until restarted (in my case)

Comment: Yeah that's the point we are trying now too. setting the timezone manually without summertime and adjusting the devices time accordingly. although this is a quite weird workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I concluded that it is a chip bug of such device.

We have explored GPS time from this device in different countries. Everythere is UTC+1.